How to expand a complex function around the point at infinity?
I came across a problem that asked to expand the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2}
$$
both around the point $z=0$ and $z=\infty$. The correct expansion around $z=0$ should be
$$
f(z) = -\sum_{k=-1}^{+\infty} \frac{(2i)^{k+2}}{(k+2)!} z^k
$$
Is there a way to directly compute the series expansion around $z=\infty$? I thought of expanding the function
$$
g(z) := -\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)
$$
at $z=0$ and I actually verified that $\operatorname{Res}\left[g(z), z=0\right] = \operatorname{Res}\left[f(z), z = \infty\right]$, so the serie expansion of $g(z)$ at $z=0$ should be the same as $f(z)$ at $z=\infty$, but I'm not completely convinced by this. The point of this post is: how do I expand $f(z)$ at $z=\infty$? Is there a way of doing that by NOT using $g(z)$? I'm asking this because my professor probably never mentioned the fact that the residue at $z=\infty$ of $f(z)$ is computed by calculating the residue of $\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ at $z=0$.

The expansion around $z=\infty$ is of the form $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ and the series is convergent for $|z|>r$ for some $r.$ In this particular case since $e^{2iz}$ is an entire function its expansion is the same at $0$ and at $\infty.$
